# How to import photos from a backend image folder with MongoDB into React?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, multer

So, I have an images folder with PNG images I would like to show on the page. The image routes are in the Seed file I have.

The image key is a Data Type of Buffer in the Schema. I'm trying to use Multer, however that so far hasn't worked. When I have that code not commented out, it shows a proxy error for one of my API's.

It works when it is commented out. Overall, not sure if I am missing something here, or what.

```
app.use(multer({ dest: "./images/",
  rename: function (fieldname, filename) {
    return filename;
  },
 }));

 app.post("/api/games",function(req,res){
  var newItem = new Item();
  newItem.img.data = fs.readFileSync(req.files.userPhoto.path)
  newItem.img.contentType = "image/png";
  newItem.save();
 });
```